# Using resulting field in ORDER BY

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I will post a simple example:

```
SELECT " CAST(t.PurchaseDate AS DATE) AS PurchaseDate
FROM SomeTable t
ORDER BT PurchaseDate
```

How can I make sure that ORDER BY will use PurchaseDate (only DATE part), and not PurchaseDate table field?

I know I can name CAST result as PurchaseDate2 (or whatever), but I do not see that as a very intuitive solution.

```
SELECT " CAST(t.PurchaseDate AS DATE) AS PurchaseDate2
FROM SomeTable t
ORDER BT PurchaseDate2
```

Also I can use CAST again:

```
ORDER BY CAST(t.PurchaseDate AS DATE)
```

but I am wondering if I can avoid double CAST?

Any ideas how can we (and can we) reference a resulting field in ORDER BY, and not the table field, when they have the same name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONVERT()` function as below which will get only DATE part

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, t.PurchaseDate) AS PurchaseDate
FROM SomeTable t
ORDER BT PurchaseDate
```

First of all, you should change the alias name to different then actual column name. Something like `NewPurchaseDate`. Not sure why you want to keep it same like actual column name.

second, you can do something like below, instead of using the `column alias` use the actual conversion processing in `order by`

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, t.PurchaseDate) AS PurchaseDate
FROM SomeTable t
ORDER BY CONVERT(date, t.PurchaseDate)
```

Comment: CAST In what way does it differ from CAST, other than being sql server specific?And how do you know for sure that PurchaseDate in Order By is not table field name?

Comment: @Goran, see edited answer. yes it's no different but keeping the alias same as column name you are actually confusing DB engine, it will order by the actual column and not the computed one.

Comment: The solution you have written is already written by me in the question, I was asking if it is possible to do explicitly specify that we are using alias and not field name.

Comment: @Goran, My answer seems same as you cause I didn't read your question properly first time. But as I have mentioned in my EDIT, to explicitly specify that you are using column alias and no the actual column; you need to give a different name; else how do you think DB engine going to know what it should use column_name/alias? What, Blam have specified in his answer is the same thing; just that he is using the column name with space and escaping it with `[]`. To that case, you can even use `Purchase_Date` as column alias; BUT by any means it has to be different. Hope it make sense now.

Comment: WHat I thought was, maybe there is a way to specify by some prefix that this is an alias, like dbo.PurchaseDate, or whatever. This way the engine could know if we want to use an alias or field. If you read the question, I asked how can we (and can we) specify in order by that we are ordering by alias, and not the field, when they have the same name.

Comment: @Goran, in a single sentence "NO, There is no such MAGIC TRICK PRESENT"

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of the '' aside....It's not a solution, as the order by clause uses table column names, not statement alias names. If you're looking for something this specific:

```
SELECT " PurchaseDate
FROM (
   SELECT " CAST(t.PurchaseDate AS DATE) AS PurchaseDate
   FROM SomeTable t
) AnotherTable
ORDER BT PurchaseDate
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean by order by clause not using aliases? I can use PurchaseDate2 in order by clause, having PurchaseDate2 as alias?

Comment: Using SELECT Column1 AS fieldN, Column1 is the column name, and FieldN is the column alias. No other clause in SQL cares about the column alias (and in fact will tell you it can't be bound), unless you wrap your first query in an outer query, where the inner aliases become the column names to the outer query.

Comment: This is not true... I can safely use fieldN Into ORDER BY clause, it will not complain...

Comment: Well, I'm unsure where I learned it, but I just tried it, and you are correct. Thanks for dispelling an incorrect view.

Answer (score 0):

Does not have the ugly factor of PurchaseDate2

```
SELECT CAST(t.PurchaseDate AS DATE) AS [Purchase Date]
  FROM SomeTable t
 ORDER BY [Purchase Date]
```

Comment: Seems like the best idea so far :)